# test google maps V3 geolocation locally ?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to test some geolocation codes on my computer, but I'm not even able to run the examples.
   Although they run perfectly from documentation website when I try to open the html file from my computer I get a blank page, all I do is trying to detect my position...

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--
    Include the maps javascript with sensor=true because this code is using a
    sensor (a GPS locator) to determine the user's location.
    See: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#SpecifyingSensor
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }

      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
          content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help, can you find out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need change the link in the stylesheet to an absolute link:

```
<link href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```